# Run ASP.NET in wamp server

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, wampserver

Is it possible to run an .aspx website in WAMP Server? If yes, then how do you do this? Please reply

Comment: I think what you want is the Mono Project: http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page  It's an open implementation of the .NET Framework for other platforms.  One thing it provides is an Apache module for interpreting ASP.NET.

Answer (score 6):

It used to be possible to have Apache interface directly with the ASP.NET engine/system via mod_aspdotnet, but that module was abandoned some time ago.

The way you do this now is to have Apache be the front-end server (port 80) and have IIS be the back-end server (8080). Then use Apache's ProxyPass directive to proxy specific websites or URLs to IIS, which runs the ASP.NET code, and give the output back to Apache, which delivers it to the visitor/client.

It's not a bad option and works well.

You just have to make sure you're either running Apache and IIS on different IPs, or same IP but different Ports.